# Playing raw audio data stream coming from BLE

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, core-bluetooth, avaudioengine

I'm Developing an iOS application.
In that I'm receiving raw data stream from `BLE`

I'm using `AVAudioEngine` with buffers

```
let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.pcmFormatInt16, sampleRate: 8000.0, channels: 1, interleaved: false)!
```

I have sample rate 8000 and linear PCM format

Initialising AVM Audio Engine using below code.

```
init() {
    self.audioSession = AVCaptureSession()
    self.engine = AVAudioEngine()
    self.playerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    self.engine.attach(self.playerNode)
    engine.connect(self.playerNode,
            to: engine.outputNode,
            format:AVAudioFormat.init(standardFormatWithSampleRate: 8000, channels: 1))
    engine.prepare()
    try! engine.start()
    self.playerNode.play()
  }
```

& playing using buffers, using below code

```
func play(buffer: [Int16]) {
    let interleavedChannelCount = 1
    let frameLength = buffer.count / interleavedChannelCount
    let audioBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(frameLength))!
    // buffer contains 2 channel interleaved data
    // audioBuffer contains 2 channel interleaved data
    var buf = buffer
    memcpy(audioBuffer.mutableAudioBufferList.pointee.mBuffers.mData, &buf, MemoryLayout<Int16>.stride * interleavedChannelCount * frameLength)
    audioBuffer.frameLength = AVAudioFrameCount(frameLength)
    self.playerNode.scheduleBuffer(audioBuffer) {
      print("Played")
    }
  }
```

& filling buffer like this,

```
let i16array = decoded.withUnsafeBytes {
            UnsafeBufferPointer<Int16>(start: $0, count: decoded.count).map(Int16.init(littleEndian:))
          }
          voicePlayer.play(buffer: i16array)
```

I'm getting crackling noise and not getting proper output.

I'm not finding any easy solution then this.
Please help me in correcting this.

Or else I am using below tutorial for playing raw audio, this approach gives me sound, but it gives me crackling noise. https://atastypixel.com/using-remoteio-audio-unit/

Which ius better way. May afterwords i need to add filter also. Please help any suggestions/code.

Comment: What kind of flow of audio do you have? It could be "push" or "pull". Depending on that you should choose solution.

Comment: @AliaksandrAndrashuk I am receiving stream of audio from BLE device, that i need to play

Comment: @ArpitBParekh can you share some code how you receive the audio?

Comment: Hello @AliaksandrAndrashuk thanks for reply, I am using below tutorial for playing raw audio, this approach gives me sound, but it gives me crackling noise. https://atastypixel.com/using-remoteio-audio-unit/

Comment: Another approach is using Audio engine, that is not giving me desired sound. That is what based on question is asked

Comment: Which would be better ?